# C# / New to LINQ, group by in query is not working out

Tags: c#, linq

var query2 = from o in db.Orders join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                 group o by o.ShipCountry into oByCountry
                 select new TotalPerCountry
                 {
                     Country = o.ShipCountry,
                     Total = oByCountry.Sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity)
                 };

For each country I need to show the total amount of money made in that country.

If you look at the diagram, I take the ShipCountry out of the Order table.
To calculate the total amount I multiply the UnitPrice by the Quantity.

I'm new to LINQ, so I'm doing some things wrong. How do I get this query right?

Also, how can I execute another query on the result of query2?
Is it by putting a name behind 'select new', so it gives the result table this name?

[image: diagram]

**EDIT:**

So we found this query as the solution:

```
            var query2 = from o in db.Orders
                     join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                     group new { o, od } by o.ShipCountry into oByCountry
                     orderby oByCountry.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity) descending
                     select new
                     {
                         Country = oByCountry.Key,
                         Total = oByCountry.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity)
                     };
```

How can I use the Country in this query in another query?
I found the below one, BUT it gives an error in the where clause.
(something regards to an anonymous type) How can I execute that query the right way?

```
            var newquery = from c in db.Customers
                    join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
                    join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                    where c.Country == query2.Country
                    group new {c, o, od} by c.CompanyName into cByName
                    orderby cByName.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity) descending
                    select new
                    {
                        cByName.Key,
                        Total = cByName.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity)
                    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are grouping `o` and not `od` so you don't have access to `od` in `oByCountry`. Include `od` in the grouping:

```
var query2 = from o in db.Orders join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
             group new { o, od } by o.ShipCountry into oByCountry
             select new TotalPerCountry
             {
                 Country = oByCountry.Key,
                 Total = oByCountry.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity)
             };
```

You can use `query2` in another query by just referencing it:

```
var TotalAs = from t in query2
              where t.Country.StartsWith("A")
              select t;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful.
Now, how can I for example use the Country column from that 'query 2 result table' in another query?

I had something like this, but it's completely wrong:

            var query = from c in db.Customers
                        join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
                        join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                        where c.Country = query2.Country
                        select c;

Comment: I believe you mean `where query2.Country.Contains(c.Country)` ? like `IN` in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help already. I've been more clear in the EDIT section of my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using group by you need to access `Key` , so instead of `Country = o.ShipCountry,` use `Country = oByCountry.key,`

```
var query2 = from o in db.Orders join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
             group o by o.ShipCountry into oByCountry
             select new TotalPerCountry
             {
                 Country = oByCountry.key,
                 Total = oByCountry.Sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity)
             };
```